# jQuery Direction Animation Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery

I have create a multilevel menu with html, css and jquery. But jquery just animate it with slide or fade. I want to animate it with direction from top to bottom and left to right look like [Menu Matic](http://greengeckodesign.com/menumatic/demos/horizontal/index.htm)

with jQuery. Have a plugin jQuery can do it? Dont use mootool or jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with plane CSS! Source: http://cssdeck.com/labs/another-simple-css3-dropdown-menu

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Portfolio
    <ul>
      <li>Web Design</li>
      <li>Web Development</li>
      <li>Illustrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS3**

```
ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your support but i want to use jQuery and your ex doesnt look like Menu Matic.

Comment: It looks better then Menu Matic. You just have to edit the CSS code, get that one above and ask how to make it look like it.

Comment: put as "solved" put the Check button on my reply. THanks